# ImageMagick works in command line but fails in Jenkins Execute shell

Tags: jenkins, imagemagick, ghostscript

One of my Jenkis CI's jobs is converting PDFs (well, in short, it just does it eventually) via ImageMagick and GhostScript. Strange thing is, when invoked from command line (via SSH) it works but started in Jenkins fails. More strange thing is that underlying gs command (convert uses gs to convert PDFs) works.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
export MAGICK_TMPDIR=`pwd`/tmp
/usr/local/bin/convert -verbose /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/example.pdf /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/example_1.jpg
```

Jenkins output:

```
[workspace] $ /bin/bash -e /var/folders/hm/dm88jd4j2f328jj96hglfbk000009c/T/hudson3825950836307624243.sh
"gs" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" "-sOutputFile=/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/tmp/magick-QkcQLTEO-%08d" "-f/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/tmp/magick-b0tr61Ng" "-f/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/tmp/magick-scEOIbtN"
convert: Postscript delegate failed `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/example.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/668.
convert: missing an image filename `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/test/workspace/example_1.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3016.
```

Jenkins v. 1.496 is running on OS X 10.7.5 with Java 1.6.0_37

Comment: Did you try to execute script from command line under jenkins users or under your user?

Comment: Note that Jenkins starts an `sh` shell, not a `bash` shell so any environment variables that would get set when you start a bash terminal will not be set. Does `convert` require any such variables to be set?

Comment: Thanks Sagar, missing PATH was the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as [Sagar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/289812/sagar) suggested, I've inspected environment variables set in terminal.
It turns out, that exporting PATH fixes the problem (which is logical as GS and IM were installed via brew to /usr/local which isn't in PATH).